# Remove a backbone model by id?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Can you remove a model by id? The documentation says you need to pass in the model itself to remove it.

So I need to fetch the model first and then remove it? I can't just remove it by id?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do you mean remove the model from a collection? Looking at the docs, it does seem like you need to pass in a real model, but the source code suggests that you can just pass in either the model `id` or the model `cid` as well, and all of the above should work (as well as arrays of all of the above).

So all of the following should be equivalent:

```
collection.remove(myModel);
collection.remove(myModel.id);
collection.remove(myModel.cid);
collection.remove([myModel]);
```

I haven't tested this, however.

Comment: Yep, looking at Backbone v1.0.0 source, the remove() function first gets the model from the collection using the get() function, which accepts a model, id or cid.

Comment: The more I use it, the more I find that Backbone is poorly documented.

Comment: Unless you read the source code :). Admittedly, that's not ideal.

Comment: I think its worthwhile to mention the `idAttribute` property in models. It tells backbone which property of the fetched models backbone should look at to determine what the `id` (in contradistinction to the `cid`) of the model is. This `id` is, ideally, the unique identifier you chose on your DB schema. See http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled upon this post (don't ask me how), the ID of a `model` is by default something like `c1` or `c23`. If you wish to remove a model by ID from the collection, then you simply get the model from the collection using:

`myCollection.get('c1');`

This will return the model with ID `c1`, if you wish to immediately remove it, you just pass the returned model to the collections `remove()` function.

`myCollection.remove( myCollection.get('c1') );`

Comment: Note that the "default" discussed here is the `cid`, not the `id`. Models do not have an id by default.